# Why does TypeScript incorrectly infer return type when using ArrayLike

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Why does Typescript infer the type of the `result` variable as `HTMLOptionElement | HTMLOptGroupElement` from this snippet if I have `ArrayLike<T>` in the `SomeType` type?:

```
type SomeType<T extends HTMLElement> = T | Array<T> | ArrayLike<T>;

function foo<T extends HTMLElement>(x: SomeType<T>): Array<T> {
    if (x instanceof HTMLElement) {
        return [x];
    }

    return Array.from(x);
}

const result = foo(new HTMLSelectElement())[0];
// TypeScript thinks result is HTMLOptionElement | HTMLOptGroupElement here, 
// instead of HTMLSelectElement
result;
```

The type is correctly inferred as `HTMLSelectElement` when I change `SomeType` to the following:

```
type SomeType<T extends HTMLElement> = T | Array<T>;
```

How can I get it to infer the result as `HTMLSelectElement` whilst keeping `ArrayLike` in the `SomeType` type?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBIBUCyAZAyhAGwgTAFEiBbCcUgN2rGQgA9IQATAZ2ToeQG8AUMhHIwcKAHMIYAFxoseQsTKUGAbkEBfQYLABPAA4pcAeyrojEADzomralwU5yEKuAB8yALzI7AH2QAQSgoOH1bL0CQsP1sYABrG3QPTQB6NINjZDMLK1t7NicMFzVPHz9kaNDwyM1BGABXEBJgUxBkGFNTApYi7hLsV3cwDwAKZnlciEtjSIBKeTshUWQoGUaoDuZkOG50TR0G5tb25AAjCTGIenB5QfwiEmGGXnB5gWFRBHbORnXOI0CIxfF1TNdbmAAHTiKQyeaaVYAoFgQ6CIA)

[Simplified Reproducer Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXBAPMqEAewIB2AJgM5QASyAsgDICiANhEgcAHxQC8UWAPlAEEATkICGITB37CxIGgEsA1hmRsA3ACgA9FtCRYiFGkzY8hUhWr0mLdlx5RpI8ZM0aAZgFcCAY2Dy4Aih3ODgTXHxiMkpaRmZCdgAKHAAuAyRUSEkASjSZF1UoAG8NKDKoeXcoZIqCEmBRXwg4KpjreNZs4tLy3qEIYE8hIIBtHABdTV6AXw0esv7B4cFnEAA6dyFEZOzNWY0fQPqofpJPBmB7ELhEgggAd0taGAgmPzjbROzskYAGSe0Wh4aBgPiE8jAl2AAAt5ARFGRTudLvJolYAPKQgIED4JRxPGiY4AAcS2njAuNYUGhEH6ABpavUIKIiFAWgSXm9gJTgBokRdNEA)

Comment: `HTMLSelectElement` is an `ArrayLike` (indices map to the corresponding `option` element in the markup).

Comment: If we check if the element is an ArrayLike, we get [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVk7qm), but it could have some undesirable behavior in the future.

Comment: @kelly thanks for this. Could you elaborate on what you mean by "undesirable behavior in the future"?

Comment: Well, you don't know when you want an array-like of array-likes, because if you use this solution, it'll likely break.

Comment: Because you told the tsc to do so. replace your foo with this and you will get the expected type function foo<T extends HTMLElement>(x: SomeType<T>){     return x; } by using the keyword as you are telling the compiler to use T as output type for foo.

Comment: @Filly I think the `as` keyword is a bit of a red herring here. Here's a simplified example without it: [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAyg9gWwgFXBAPMqEAewIB2AJgM5QASyAsgDICiANhEgcAHxQC8UWAPlAEEATkICGITB37CxIGgEsA1hmRsA3ACgNAMwCuBAMbB5cAlG1w4mbHkKkK1ekxbsAFDgBcsRCjSSAlF4y4pJQAN4aUFFQ8tpQ7jEEJMCihhBwcZS0jMyEwP7hkdHFQhDAukJmANo4ALqaxQC+WiVlFWbBIAB02kKI7v6azTr6RiZmAEaiQq4FEcUGpslQpSS6DMBc5pauBBAA7g60MBBMRjkus-5VAAz1RVGr68BDGkA)